# Wordnet SQL Setup

Tags: mysql, wordnet

I'm trying to setup the wordnet sql database (http://wnsql.sourceforge.net/). I downloaded this file http://sourceforge.net/projects/wnsql/files/wnsql3/mysql/3.1/ and tried to run the .sh file on my macbook pro. After entering the database name and password I get the following error:

```
restore-mysql.sh: line 45: mysql: command not found
schema wn
restore-mysql.sh: line 27: mysql: command not found
data wn
restore-mysql.sh: line 27: mysql: command not found
unconstrain wn
constrain wn
restore-mysql.sh: line 27: mysql: command not found
views wn
restore-mysql.sh: line 27: mysql: command not found
```

Does anybody know how to install the database properly?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have MySQL installed.

Comment: I do! MySQL server status is "running".

Comment: What is the output of ```which mysql``` ? I am suspecting you have the server installed, but not the client.

Comment: I don't get any output for which mysql in the command line so you're probably right! Is there a way to just install the client as I already installed the server? I can only find the full mysql download package!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the discussion in the comments, the solution for Debian-like Linux distributions (apt) would be:

`apt-get install mysql-client`

For RedHat-like (yum)

`yum install mysql-client`

for others (including non-Linux) check the documentation.